# "To take care" meaning "to serve"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can the verb "take care" be used in the sense of "to serve" "or perform the functions of a waiter in the case of the example below?

> What do I do at the restaurant? Well, I make juices, coffee, wash the dishes, things like that. And if there are a lot of customers, I take care of some tables as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No and Yes.

The expression to "take care of" something means to handle an issue, fix a problem, deal with a situation etc. -- all very general. There's no specific meaning of serving as a waiter. No dictionary will say "fix" has the sense of "*replace a bicycle's rear derailleur tension spring*", and in the same way, "take care of" doesn't have the sense of performing the functions of a waiter.

THAT SAID, having too many customers for the regular wait staff is a situation that needs to be dealt with, so it's 100% natural to say, "*I take care of some tables*".